# Как можно объединить три функции в одну?

Tags: c++, функции, перегрузка-функций

Я хочу объединить эти функции в одну и не знаю как это сделать. возможно ли это.
Можно даже в класс или структуру не особо важно.

```
template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
auto vector_ptr(T1& size1, T2& size2, T3& size3) {
auto result = make_shared<vector<vector<vector<int>>>>(size1, vector<vector<int>>(size2, vector<int>(size3)));
return *result;
}

template<class T1, class T2>
auto vector_ptr(T1& size1, T2& size2) {
auto result = make_shared<vector<vector<int>>>(size1, vector<int>(size2));
return *result;
}

template<class T1>
auto vector_ptr(T1& size1) {
auto result = make_shared<vector<int>>(size1);
return *result;
}

// Вызов
auto varr1 = vector_ptr(size1);
auto varr2 = vector_ptr(size1, size2);
auto varr3 = vector_ptr(size1, size2, size3);
```

Я думаю сделать больше вариантов таких как size4 и size5 хочу увидеть как объединить подобные функции что бы не было ограничений, в данном случае сейчас только 3 варианта. Но это только пока 3, хотя меня больше интересует сам способ реализации.

Еще я не могу отвечать на комментарии кнопка не работает пух.

Comment: А в чем здесь смысл шаблонов?

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, зачем вам тут шаблоны?...

Во-вторых, а что вы сделали, как не определили три функции с одним именем - все прекрасно компилируется и работает. Разве что выбросьте шаблоны, перегрузка прекрасно [справляется и так](https://ideone.com/bwqCk6):

```
auto vector_ptr(int size1, int size2, int size3) {
    auto result = make_shared<vector<vector<vector<int>>>>(size1,
                              vector<vector<int>>(size2, vector<int>(size3)));
    return *result;
}

auto vector_ptr(int size1, int size2) {
    auto result = make_shared<vector<vector<int>>>(size1, vector<int>(size2));
    return *result;
}

auto vector_ptr(int size1) {
    auto result = make_shared<vector<int>>(size1);
    return *result;
}

int main()
{
    int size1 = 2, size2 = 3, size3 = 4;
    auto varr1 = vector_ptr(size1);
    cout << typeid(varr1).name() << endl;
    auto varr2 = vector_ptr(size1, size2);
    cout << typeid(varr2).name() << endl;
    auto varr3 = vector_ptr(size1, size2, size3);
    cout << typeid(varr3).name() << endl;
}
```

Или я неверно вас понял? тогда поясните подробнее, что вы хотите... Возвращать из *единственной* функции разные типы? :)

Comment: я думаю умный указатель тут абсолютно излишный. Просто возвращать  вектор...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Я согласен, но вдруг человеку зачем-то нужен именно `shared_ptr`? :)